# Gerar arquivo com nome dinâmico Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estou criando socket de comunicação de alguns dispositivos com servidor.
Preciso que esses dispositivos gravem as informações sempre no mesmo arquivo. 
O nome do arquivo precisa ser os primeiros caracteres dentro da sua mensagem.

```
import socket
import _thread

HOST = '192.168.0.63'
PORT = 5000

def conectado(con, cliente,):
    print ('Conectado por', cliente)

    while True:
        msg = con.recv(1024)
        if not msg: break
        print (cliente, msg,)

        arquivo = open(conectado, 'a+')
        arquivo.write(str(msg))
        arquivo.write('\n')
        arquivo.close()


    print ('Finalizando conexao do cliente', cliente)
    con.close()
    _thread.exit()

tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

orig = (HOST, PORT)

tcp.bind(orig)
tcp.listen(1)

while True:
    con, cliente = tcp.accept()
    _thread.start_new_thread(conectado, tuple([con, cliente,]))

tcp.close()
```

O dispositivo enviaria ASCII, iniciando por 8 números, que representam seu ID.
Ao tentar executar o código me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function conectado at 0x7fd4ed513e18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/projeto1/projeto1.py", line 15, in conectado
    arquivo = open(conectado, 'a+')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not function
```

Comment: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object`, ou seja, era esperado string, bytes ou objeto PathLike na função `open`. Você passa `conectado` para a função open, só que `conectado` não é string, e sim a função que está sendo executada.

Comment: Como eu faço pro script definir qual será o nome do dispositivo? De acordo com a mensagem que ele vai receber

Comment: `arquivo = open(conectado, 'a+')`, aqui você tenta abrir o arquivo `conectado`, mas esse objeto é uma função.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O correto de utilizar é:

```
arquivo = open("log_" + str(msg) + ".txt",'a+')
```